# Can I have the git-log "--all" option be initially selected?

Tags: magit

When I press the "l" key in the main Magit status mode, it pops up a window where I can adjust the options to be passed to the `magit log` command.  Can I arrange for the `--all` option to always be initially selected, just as the `--graph` option is?

Comment: The day will come when you don't want that, but by then it will be too late.

Comment: See [`magit-key-mode.el:715`](https://github.com/magit/magit/blob/8834213122cbba749009a23aba5e824e23f0d155/magit-key-mode.el#L715)

Comment: Too late for what?

Comment: Oh, my apologies :) I mistook the `--all` option to display, well, *all* of the log entries. My mistake! :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can define a custom command to do what you want, and bind it to `l` to override the default behavior:

```el
(defun magit-log-all ()
  (interactive)
  (magit-key-mode-popup-logging)
  (magit-key-mode-toggle-option (quote logging) "--all"))

(define-key magit-mode-map (kbd "l") 'magit-log-all)
```

With this in place, pressing <kbd>l</kbd> in `magit-mode` automatically selects the `--all` option in the menu that comes up.

---

#### Additional information

In case you are curious, here is how I arrived at the solution above: There are two steps involved in what you are currently doing to set options for `git log`. First, you bring up the menu for choosing options by pressing <kbd>l</kbd>. To tell `magit` to pass the `--all` option to `git log`, you then have to press `-al`. If you want to define a custom command to automate this process, you need to know which commands are bound to these key presses. This information can be obtained by pressing <kbd>C-h c</kbd> (`describe-key-briefly`) or <kbd>C-h k</kbd> (`describe-key`) followed by the key sequence you want to examine.

1. <kbd>C-h c</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd> in a `magit-mode` buffer gives:

   > `l` runs the command `magit-key-mode-popup-logging`
2. <kbd>C-h c</kbd> <kbd>-al</kbd> *after pressing* <kbd>l</kbd> in a `magit-mode` buffer gives:

   > `- a l` runs the command `(lambda nil (interactive) (magit-key-mode-toggle-option (quote logging) "--all"))`

Equipped with this information, all that's left to do is create a command that calls the relevant functions in the right order.

Comment: I'd been hoping for a configuration setting, but this'll work fine.  Other options include advising `magit-key-mode-popup-logging` and binding `l` to a keyboard macro.

Comment: @Sean I would open an issue on GitHub – it is noted in the code as something that needs to be made better; perhaps they were waiting for someone with the need.

Comment: No need for that, on the next branch support for setting default arguments is already implemented.

Answer (score 2):

Beginning with `v2.1.0` Magit's logging popup no longer features the `--all` infix argument. Instead the popup provides three new related *suffix commands*.

- <kbd>l L</kbd> Log local branches (`--branches`)
- <kbd>l b</kbd> Log all branches (`--branches --remotes`)
- <kbd>l a</kbd> Log all references (`--all`)

While it is no longer possible (or necessary) to set the `--all` argument, you might want to change the default value of some other argument. See [How can I make `--verbose` flag be enabled by default in magit commit screen?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/3893) for information about that.