# How can I make `--verbose` flag be enabled by default in magit commit screen?

Tags: magit

Right now, instead of pressing just `cc` in magit-mode, I have to press `c-vc` every time to enable `--verbose`.

Is it possible to make it enabled by default?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Beginning with `v2.1.0`, Magit uses the library `magit-popup.el` to implement such "popup buffers" or "prefix-infix-suffix combos". Despite its name, that library can be used by packages not related to Magit, and is therefore made available as a separate Elpa package. It even has its [own manual](http://magit.vc/manual/magit-popup/#Top) now!

Default arguments can now be set directly from a popup buffer. To always use `--verbose` when committing do this:

1. <kbd>c</kbd> Show the committing popup
2. <kbd>- v</kbd> Turn on `--verbose`
3. <kbd>C-x C-s</kbd> Save the currently set arguments as defaults (in the custom option `magit-commit-arguments`)

By default all popup buffers end with a section named "Common Commands". If not, use <kbd>C-t</kbd> to show it. You probably don't want to see that section all the time and should therefore set `magit-popup-show-common-commands` to `nil`.

Of course it is also possible to set the value of `magit-commit-arguments` and other such variables using the Custom interface, `setq`, or `add-to-list`. But I recommend against that, because that would make it impossible to change the defaults on-the-fly.

Answer (score 7):

As far as I can tell Magit does not keep track of "default" options, but we can make **it** "press `-v`" every time the Committing buffer pops up:

```
(advice-add #'magit-key-mode-popup-committing :after
            (lambda ()
              (magit-key-mode-toggle-option (quote committing) "--verbose")))
```

To find what function to advise, I opened a `magic-status` buffer and pressed `C-h k c`. This led me to `magit-key-mode-popup-committing`. Then (with the Committing buffer still displayed) I pressed `C-h k -v` to find the `lambda` form Magit calls when *you* press `-v` in the Committing window.

**Update:** I did write this answer independently, but see [Can I have the git-log “--all” option be initially selected?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/3289/2355), the answer given there, and comments to that answer.

Comment: That's interesting! Thank you for also explaining how you found those functions :)

Comment: @Dogbert: please see the link in the updated answer if you care to know that others thought about default git options not that long ago. :-) (I don't know how I missed that yesterday.)

Answer (score 5):

In the versions of magit that use transient (after February 2019 or so), set the flag, and then save while still in the transient buffer.

So for commit, the key sequence would be something like

```
C-x g # start magit
s # to stage changes
c # start commiting
-v # enable verbose
C-x C-s # Save the setting persistently across sessions
c # do the actual commit
```

After that, next time commit is invoked, verbose will still be set. (You do not have to complete the commit, and can exit after saving with `C-x C-s`.)

The actual default is saved in a `transient/` directory in `.emacs.d/`.

See the transient manual https://magit.vc/manual/transient.html#Saving-Values

Answer (score 0):

While it's not exactly what you want (diff in your commit buffer), you can set magit to expand the staged diffs in the **status** window:

```
(setq magit-expand-staged-on-commit 'full)
```

The magit workflow seems to always be open status buffer and then open split with commit buffer, you always end up with two buffers displayed. The above setting will make the second (previously not useful) buffer display your diff.

You can also use `t` to only expand the diff headers (so it shows the line numbers):

```
(setq magit-expand-staged-on-commit t)
```

While writing your diff, you can switch to the status buffer and use `TAB` to expand (or fold) the diffs.

---

Alternatively, you can use `C-c C-d` from the commit buffer to open another buffer with a diff with `magit-diff-staged`. (See [this issue](https://github.com/magit/magit/issues/946).)

Answer (score 0):

As of `magit` version `2.1`, you can use this in your config:

```
;; When commiting enable verbose mode by default.
(setq magit-commit-arguments (quote ("--verbose")))
```

Comment: You shouldn't do that. See my answer.

Comment: @tarsius You have a valid point. My usecase is that I sync my dotfiles between multiple computers and when I set a default it should be default on all my computers. If I want to change it, I'll just change it in my config and it will be synced across all my computers.

Comment: Oh and I don't use the custom options because it makes my config hard to document. I prefer to set everything explicitly.

Comment: Also, setting `--no-verify` is useful when you have projects that use git hooks (use with caution, obviously).