# how to add a default-on option of magit log

Tags: spacemacs, magit

Since the 'log --graph' is slow in the repo with long history, I wanna
add '--since' option for it.
I tried to add the following lines in my '.spacemacs' file.

```
(magit-define-popup-option 'magit-log-popup                                                                                                                                                             
                            ?x                                                                                                                                                                          
                            "Since date"                                                                                                                                                                
                            "--since="                                                                                                                                                                  
                            nil                                                                                                                                                                         
                            (org-read-date nil nil "-1y")                                                                                                                                               
                            )
```

but it doesn't work. so I wonder how to make it.

Comment: the option is added, but it is not default-on with the value of 'one year before' as I set

Comment: This worked for me: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/13683/6682

Answer (score 1):

I made it by following lines, but I don't know if my setting was wrong before.

```
(custom-set-variables                                                                                                                                                                                   
     '(magit-log-arguments                                                                                                                                                                                  
       (list "--graph" "--decorate" "-n256"                                                                                                                                                                 
             (concatenate 'string "--since=" (org-read-date nil nil "-1y"))                                                                                                                                 
             )                                                                                                                                                                                              
       )                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    )
```